# How to scrape xml urls with scrapy

Tags: python, xml, scrapy

Hi i am working on scrapy to scrape xml urls

Suppose below is my spider.py code

```
class TestSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "test"
    allowed_domains = {"www.example.com"}


    start_urls = [
        "https://example.com/jobxml.asp"
        ]


    def parse(self, response):
        print response,"??????????????????????"
```

**result:**

```
2012-07-24 16:43:34+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.14.3 started (bot: testproject)
2012-07-24 16:43:34+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, MemoryUsage, SpiderState
2012-07-24 16:43:34+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2012-07-24 16:43:34+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2012-07-24 16:43:34+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
2012-07-24 16:43:34+0530 [test] INFO: Spider opened
2012-07-24 16:43:34+0530 [test] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2012-07-24 16:43:34+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2012-07-24 16:43:34+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2012-07-24 16:43:36+0530 [testproject] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://example.com/jobxml.asp> (failed 1 times): 400 Bad Request
2012-07-24 16:43:37+0530 [test] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://example.com/jobxml.asp> (failed 2 times): 400 Bad Request
2012-07-24 16:43:38+0530 [test] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET https://example.com/jobxml.asp> (failed 3 times): 400 Bad Request
2012-07-24 16:43:38+0530 [test] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <GET https://example.com/jobxml.asp> (referer: None)
2012-07-24 16:43:38+0530 [test] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2012-07-24 16:43:38+0530 [test] INFO: Dumping spider stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 651,
     'downloader/request_count': 3,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 504,
     'downloader/response_count': 3,
     'downloader/response_status_count/400': 3,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 24, 11, 13, 38, 573931),
     'scheduler/memory_enqueued': 3,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 24, 11, 13, 34, 803202)}
2012-07-24 16:43:38+0530 [test] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
2012-07-24 16:43:38+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping global stats:
    {'memusage/max': 263143424, 'memusage/startup': 263143424}
```

Whether scrapy does n't work for xml scraping, if yes can anyone please provide me an example on how to scrape xml tag data

Thanks in advance...........

Comment: Where does the log output come from? Where are the HTTP requests executed?

Comment: @Tichodroma : I had edited my actual result above please have a look at ti

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a specific spider made for scraping xml feeds. This is from scrapy documentation:

XMLFeedSpider example

These spiders are pretty easy to use, let’s have a look at one example:

```
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import XMLFeedSpider
from myproject.items import TestItem

class MySpider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/feed.xml']
    iterator = 'iternodes' # This is actually unnecesary, since it's the default value
    itertag = 'item'

    def parse_node(self, response, node):
        log.msg('Hi, this is a <%s> node!: %s' % (self.itertag, ''.join(node.extract())))

        item = Item()
        item['id'] = node.select('@id').extract()
        item['name'] = node.select('name').extract()
        item['description'] = node.select('description').extract()
        return item
```

This is another way without scrapy:

This is a function used to download xml from given url, note that some import are not in here and this will also give you a nice progress for downloading xml file.

```
def get_file(self, dir, url, name):
    s = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    f = open('xml/test.xml','w')
    meta = s.info()
    file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
    print "Downloading: %s Bytes: %s" % (name, file_size)
    current_file_size = 0
    block_size = 4096
    while True:
        buf = s.read(block_size)
        if not buf:
            break
        current_file_size += len(buf)
        f.write(buf)
        status = ("\r%10d  [%3.2f%%]" %
                 (current_file_size, current_file_size * 100. / file_size))
        status = status + chr(8)*(len(status)+1)
        sys.stdout.write(status)
        sys.stdout.flush()
    f.close()
    print "\nDone getting feed"
    return 1
```

And then you parse that xml file that you downloaded and saved with iterparse, something like:

```
for event, elem in iterparse('xml/test.xml'):
        if elem.tag == "properties":
            print elem.text
```

That's just an example how do you go through xml tree.

Also, this is an old code of mine, so you would be better of using with for opening files.

Comment: Thanks for u r reply, the only thing i had done is inheriting from XMLFeedSpider as u mentioned, and i had run the code still the same problem retrying retrying....., is this the problem of url(becuase it very lengthy actually approximately total size is 7.6 mb if we save this to local desktop)

Comment: it shouldn't be a problem at all xml feeds are usually couple of mb on size, but I can't tell you for sure cause I've never used this spider, for the feeds I actually used simple urllib2 to download xmlfeed and then iterparse to parse through it if you want I can send you an sample of that aproach

Comment: Note: The scrapy example comes directly from https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#xmlfeedspider-example